# JSF with Spring Controllors

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-mvc, jsf-2

I am new to Spring and JSF,and I want to integrate JSF for the front end, and use Spring controller. Can Anyone give me a explanation or an example how this can be done?. Basically what I want is a form submission (which will create a Business object and feed it to the database) and navigate using controllers.

1. The required xml files ? and its element?
2. A Basic form( ex: Like a User registration )
3. Spring class with `@Controller`, and `@RequestMapping` etc.

I just want to know how the form submission works and the flow of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to integrate Spring with JSF you don't need to use `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping`, those are for SpringMVC. JSF itself has navigation mechanism use that.

If you need example check [Integrate Spring into JSF 2](http://murygin.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/integrate-spring-jsf/)